# Strange formatting issue when file saved as html and php

Tags: php, html

When the file saved as a html file everything renders fine but when file saved as php it looks like there is a open tag. The open tag mentioned is the is a simple `" "< "` and can be seen on the live php page http://bit.ly/v267Nh. Also here is the html version of the same file where `" "< "` is not rendered http://bit.ly/t26igR. There is no php script within the file so what you see in the source is the actual html source.

When i view the source in Firefox "> character encoding but i have no idea how it is rendered since there is no php script that is generating the html code. Here is the code as it appears in the code editor.

```
<h1>All Purpose Cleaning Kit</h1>
<p>Safer and powerful cleaning action that removes grease, oil and heavy soiling from appliances, counters, tables, shelves, ﬂoors, doors, walls, and all other hard surfaces in and around your home.   </p><br />
<p><b>Comes With Everything Pictured:</b>   Kit Box, 32 oz. Spray Bottle, 12 oz. Concentrate, Push/Pull Cap, Micro-Fiber Cloth<br /><br /><b>Concentrate Makes Up To (6) 32 oz. Spray Bottles (1 1/2 Gallons)</b><br />
<div class="bottles"><img src="imgs/smallbottles.png" width="210" height="75"></div>
</p> <table width="450" border="1" class="pricetable">
```

Comment: Validate your HTML at validator.w3.org. You'll likely find your problem then.

Comment: You should probably link some code

Comment: @meagar FYI, the double-quotes in the original posting were important

Comment: PHP source would be great. is your string in a double quote or single quote?

Comment: There is no php code none whatsoever in this file.Pure html saved as php file.

Comment: @hafichuk Assumed it was a terrible attempt to escape less-than signs.

Comment: I'd run both version of the sources through `diff` (linux/mac) or `windiff` (windows) just to make sure that they are the same.

Comment: Here is one big detail that i failed to mention which also escaped me totally. Site is hosted at yahoo eCommerce platform which supports; so called, store tags that are formatted like so "<!--#ystore_order id="glassappliancekit" -->".I believe there might be some conflicts when php and yahoo store tags combined.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your php source code it's impossible to tell.

Search through the source and try to find `<div class="bottles">`, there is an empty paragraph underneath it and under that is your bracket. If I were to guess, it's probably one too many double-quotes.

By the way, take a look at Google Chromes "Inspector" or Firefox's Firebug plugin. It'll help you to pin point these sort of issues.

Update #1:

There are quite a few javascript errors which *may* be causing this. It's happening on both versions of your page so it's unlikely, but you never know.